# I want to display date picker in textfield with remove selected date in textfield

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to display date picker in textfield with remove selected date in textfield.

To choose date i use tappable image and the selected date set in the textfield but i can't remove that date from textfield.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          LightText(
            text: ' ${widget.labelTxt}',
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 3),
          ),
          Container(
            height: 24,
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(3)),
            child: Theme(
              data: ThemeData(hintColor: lightGrey),
              child: TextField(
                enabled: isEditForInputField
                    ? !widget.enableVal ? false : true
                    : false,
                controller: widget.controllerText,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  suffix: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: (){
                      isEditForInputField
                            ? _selectDate(context, widget.value,
                                widget.firebaseKey, widget.index)
                            : null;
                    },
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 7.0, right: 3.0,),
                      child: Image.asset('assets/images/calendar.png',
                        height: 25.0,
                        width: 25.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),

                    disabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
                    ),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        vertical: 3.0, horizontal: 5.0)),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this one.

Create a widget as below,

```
     Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                color: Colors.grey[300],
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                width: double.infinity,
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    openDatePicker(dateValue);
                  },
                  child: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        flex: 9,
                        child: Text(dateValue),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        flex: 1,
                        child: Icon(Icons.calendar_today),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
             ],
            ),
```

Add this code to your stateful widget,

```
String dateValue = "Select Date";
  DateTime selectedDate = DateTime.now();

  openDatePicker(initialDateString) async {
    var initialDate = convertToDate(initialDateString) ?? selectedDate;
    initialDate =
        (initialDate.year >= 1900 && initialDate.isBefore(selectedDate)
            ? initialDate
            : selectedDate);

    final DateTime pickedDate = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: initialDate,
      firstDate: DateTime(2018, 1),
      lastDate: DateTime(3000),
    );
    if (pickedDate != null && pickedDate != selectedDate) {
      setState(() {
        selectedDate = pickedDate;
        dateValue = new DateFormat.yMd().format(pickedDate);
      });
    }
  }

  DateTime convertToDate(String input) {
    try {
      var d = new DateFormat.yMd().parseStrict(input);
      return d;
    } catch (e) {
      return null;
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    dateValue = new DateFormat.yMd().format(selectedDate);
  }
```

You will now easily manage your date. If you want to remove your selected date from text then create another widget like IconButton or anything else suitable for you. Then onPress of that widget set the dateValue to empty and setState your widget.

This will help you.

Comment: Thanks,  i don't want to create new widget i want to handle that part with textfield.